# Azure SQL: Can tempdb size cause a large query to go exceed its size limit?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have two BI reporting servers (one is Development, the other Production) each with their own own Azure SQL instance, I am using Pentaho to automate the ETL process and part of my process is to execute a query joining two tables of similar data in order to join a user's **login** row with their **logout** row.

```
with login_cte as 
    (
        select
             os.[k_actions]
            ,[k_hosts]
            ,[k_logger_names]
            ,[k_principals]
            ,[k_sites]
            ,[k_roles]
            ,[k_date] as k_date_logged_in
            ,[k_time] as k_time_logged_in
            ,[k_date_ct] as k_date_ct_logged_in
            ,[k_time_ct] as k_time_ct_logged_in
            ,[key] as key_logged_in
            ,[type]
            ,[id]
            ,[sort]
            ,[level]
            ,[timestamp_utc] as timestamp_utc_logged_in
            ,[timestamp_ct] as timestamp_ct_logged_in
            ,[service]
            ,[version]
            ,[message] as message_logged_in
            ,[thread_name]
            ,[db_name]
            ,[customer_id]
        from other_stage os
        left join dim_actions da on os.k_actions = da.k_actions
        where [action_name] = 'SET_ROLE_DEVICE_USER'
        order by [key] asc
        offset 0 rows
    ),
    logout_cte as 
    (
        select 
             [k_actions]
            ,[k_hosts] as k_hosts_out
            ,[k_logger_names] as k_logger_names_out
            ,[k_principals] as k_principals_out
            ,[k_sites] as k_sites_out
            ,null as k_roles_out
            ,[k_date] as k_date_logged_out
            ,[k_time] as k_time_logged_out
            ,[k_date_ct] as k_date_ct_logged_out
            ,[k_time_ct] as k_time_ct_logged_out
            ,[key] as key_logged_out
            ,[type] as type_out
            ,[id] as id_out
            ,[sort] as sort_out
            ,[level] as level_out
            ,[timestamp_utc] as timestamp_utc_logged_out
            ,[timestamp_ct] as timestamp_ct_logged_out
            ,[service] as service_out
            ,[version] as version_out
            ,[message] as message_logged_out
            ,[thread_name] as thread_name_out
            ,[db_name]
            ,[customer_id]
        from logout_stage
        order by [key] asc
        offset 0 rows
    )
select 
     li.k_actions
    ,li.k_hosts
    ,li.k_logger_names
    ,li.k_principals
    ,li.k_roles
    ,li.k_sites
    ,li.k_date_logged_in
    ,li.k_time_logged_in
    ,lo.k_date_logged_out
    ,lo.k_time_logged_out
    ,li.k_date_ct_logged_in
    ,li.k_time_ct_logged_in
    ,lo.k_date_ct_logged_out
    ,lo.k_time_ct_logged_out
    ,li.key_logged_in
    ,lo.key_logged_out
    ,li.type
    ,li.id
    ,li.sort
    ,li.level
    ,li.timestamp_utc_logged_in
    ,li.timestamp_ct_logged_in
    ,lo.timestamp_utc_logged_out
    ,lo.timestamp_ct_logged_out
    ,li.service
    ,li.version
    ,li.message_logged_in
    ,lo.message_logged_out
    ,li.thread_name
    ,li.db_name
    ,li.customer_id
    ,datediff(second, li.timestamp_utc_logged_in, lo.timestamp_utc_logged_out) as login_duration
    ,row_number() over (partition by li.key_logged_in order by lo.key_logged_out asc) as rn
from login_cte li left join logout_cte lo
on li.k_principals = lo.k_principals_out
and li.db_name = lo.db_name
and lo.key_logged_out > li.key_logged_in
and lo.timestamp_utc_logged_out > li.timestamp_utc_logged_in
order by lo.key_logged_out asc
```

The issue I'm having is that this query runs just fine by itself in my production instance but when run on the development instance, which has fewer rows in each table (~70k vs ~124k), the query fails with this error.

`SQLServerException: The database 'tempdb' has reached its size quota. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the documentation for possible resolutions.`

Doing some digging into the tempdb size on each I ran this query:

```
SELECT SUM(unallocated_extent_page_count) AS [free pages],
  (SUM(unallocated_extent_page_count)*1.0/128) AS [free space in MB]
FROM tempdb.sys.dm_db_file_space_usage;
```

With these results:

Production:

| free pages | free space in MB |
| --- | --- |
| 923,792 | 7,217.125 |

Development:

| free pages | free space in MB |
| --- | --- |
| 8,386,864 | 65,522.375 |

while the query is running I can run file space usage query again and watch the free space slow go done to zero then the query fails. Meanwhile the same query on Production shows the free space go down but never hits zero and will succeed.

I am fairly new to Azure SQL and have tried searching for an answer but can only find answers on how to find a query that is using up the tempdb (of which I already know...) but not any on what would cause the same query to fail on one and not the other. I do not have access to the Azure console but can connect to the DB with a power user through either DBeaver or Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Edit 12-14-21:

[Paste of the query execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyiZBO8qt)

Comment: It could be many things, couple of the top of my head: 1. you are missing some indexes/statistics in Dev that causes inefficient query plan to be used; 2. It could be "crappy data" e.g. many duplicate rows producing a Cartesian join.

Comment: @Alex, 1: so currently there are no indexes on the tables, as far as construction goes, the tables are identical. 
2: it could very well be crappy data given the nature of this data coming from a dev environment and being Development and testing data... what kind of duplicates would I be looking for? coming from one of the tables being joined or from inside the joined data?

Comment: Really need to see the execution plan for the problematic query - 
[PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan). Many things will use temp DB including hash joins and sort spills. I believe in Azure the default isolation is RCSI which uses tempDB as a rowstore.

Comment: You are looking for join column duplicates e.g. columns `os.k_actions` and `da.k_actions` in a `os.k_actions = da.k_actions` condition. But @Stu is correct: without a query plan we are just guessing.